# Why does the trigger get executed multiple times when updating the table in interactive grid?

Tags: sql, triggers, oracle-apex, apex

I created a trigger to send an email notification if a table is updated, now the table is actually an interactive grid with an "Update" button which actually updates through PL/SQL procedure and consist of 5 sections, once the table is updated the email will be sent 5 times based on the number of rows and I don't want this to happen.

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EMP_NOTIFICATION_TRG
   AFTER UPDATE 
   ON POCT_ASSESSMENT_HEADER
   REFERENCING OLD AS old NEW AS new
   FOR EACH ROW
   DECLARE
   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
   l_id             NUMBER;
   l_emp_cpr        NUMBER;
   l_emp_email      VARCHAR2 (100);

   BEGIN
   IF UPDATING
   THEN
    IF  :OLD.HEADER_ID IS NOT NULL
    THEN
        SELECT EMP_EMAIL
          INTO l_emp_email
          FROM POCT_ASSESSMENT_HEADER
         WHERE HEADER_ID = :OLD.HEADER_ID;



        IF l_emp_email IS NOT NULL
        THEN 



                APEX_MAIL.SEND (
                    p_to     => l_emp_email,       --l_official_email,
                    p_cc     => '',
                    p_bcc    => '',
                    p_from   => 'POCT@org.bh',
                    p_subj   => 'Assessment Acknowledgment',
                    p_body   => '',
                    p_body_html   =>
                           '<p>Please be advised that you were assessed for the below test:,</p>
     <p>Test Name: <b>'
                        || :old.TEST_NAME
                        || '</b></p>
     <p>Bondy Score:  <b>'
                        || :NEW.BONDY_SCORE
                        || '</b></p>
     <p>Level of Achievment:   <b>'
                        || :NEW.LEVEL_ACHIEVEMENT
                        || '</b></p>
     <p>Date:  <b>'
                        || :NEW.FORM_DATE
                        || '</b></p>
    ');     
   APEX_MAIL.PUSH_QUEUE;




ELSIF INSERTING THEN
NULL;


ELSIF DELETING then

null;

END IF;
END IF;
END IF;
 END;
```

Comment: What does "consist of 5 sections" mean?  Is your process updating every row in the table?  If there are 5 rows in the table and your APEX process is updating all 5 rows then, clearly, a row-level trigger on the table will fire 5 times.  Assuming that is the case, you'd likely want to change your process to only update rows where there is a change or add logic to the trigger that only sends an email if something has changed.  Separately, declaring that the trigger is an autonomous transaction is almost certainly a mistake.

Comment: @Justin Cave I am new to this, I cannot figure a close logic for the trigger to be handled separately

Comment: Presumably you did so in order to be able to query the table on which the trigger is defined.  First, you presumably only need to access the email from the `:old` pseudorecord.  Second, your trigger would read the data as it existed before the current transaction changed it which seems unlikely to be what you want.  Third, you'd commit any changes made by the trigger even if the underlying transaction was rolled back which is very unlikely to be what you want.  Assuming `header_id` is the primary key, it would also be impossible for `:old.header_id` to be `null` on an update.

Comment: I don't know what "trigger to be handled separately" means to you.

Comment: @JustinCave the trigger needs to read both old and new data and yes header_id is the PK, is there any other way for the trigger to work instead of row-level way?

Comment: If you want to access the `:new` and `:old` pseudorecords, the trigger would need to be defined as a row-level trigger.  It should not be defined to use an autonomous transaction.  You would either need to check to see whether there was a change that you consider "interesting" in the trigger logic or you would need to change the process logic not to update rows where there are no changes.  It would seem logical not to update rows if there are no changes particularly as the number of rows increases over time.

Comment: You could add a separated column (eg SEND_EMAIL NUMBER(1)) to your table and only update that column in 1 of your 5 sections. Then change your trigger to ```after UPDATE of send_email ON POCT_ASSESSMENT_HEADER```
Or... fix your code so it only does a single update instead of 5

Comment: Unrelated comment - you have "PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION" - 99% sure that is not needed - that needs to be used only in very specific exceptional cases. If you're not sure what it is for, remove it from your all your code.